# Increasing Cygwin's memory allocation

Tags: git, cygwin, registry

I just added a ton of images to my local git repo.  As a result, when I try to push to our remote repo, I get the error:

```
fatal: out of memory, malloc failed76)
```

My hypothesis is that this is due to a lack of memory allocated to Cygwin.  I've tried to increase Cygwin's memory by following [these instructions](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-maxmem.html) but i can't find the registry entries it mentions.

Anyone have any advice?

Comment: If the registry entries aren't there (yet), you'll need to add them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled the example program they have on the site without making any modifications to my system, and I get this:

```
5fffe000 bytes (1536.0Mb)
```

Which looks right, and is more than the 384MB maximum that they mention. Perhaps this documentation is for an older version of cygwin.

Note however that I am using the newer cygwin 1.7.

If the keys don't exist you could create them, but once again the documentation looks old.

HKLM/Software/Cygwin seems like the new regkey

Comment: I don't have Admin Rights, I had to use HKCU/Software/Cygwin .  But this worked fine.